# Laravel strip_tags and str::words not working correct?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this kind of code in my view blade:

```
<p class="article">
   {!! strip_tags((Str::words($article->article, 25))) !!}
</p>
```

I want to show only the first 25 words, but sometimes it works, sometimes not. Look at the image.

P.S. Text is a writer with TinyMCE and has a lot of HTML tags.

What can be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supposed to strip tags, and then limit words (reverse order).

```
{!! Str::words(strip_tags($article->article), 25) !!}
```

Also if this text do not supposed to be HTML code, should use `{{ }}` instead `{!! !!}` to avoid XSS attacks.

```
{{ Str::words(strip_tags($article->article), 25) }}}
```

Another tip will be with `Str::words`. Since words can be very short or very long, and based on your screen columns should be in similar height then limiting chars instead of words will be better idea.

```
{{ Str::limit(strip_tags($article->article), 250) }}}
```

Comment: I'm glad @David :) Then please accept answer if question is solved.

Comment: Today I noticed some bug of that code. In my language, we have some special letter such a "š", "į", and more. And now I got this:                                                       Mažeikių rajono savivaldybė dėl &scaron; vietimo įstaigų vadovų trūkumo planuoja lop&scaron;elius - darželius jungti prie moky...                                                               As you can see instead of some letters I get it: &scaron;                                                         How can I fix it? @chojnicki

Comment: @David its just encoding issue in some of used functions or {{ }}, test it

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
{!! Str::words(strip_tags($article->article), 25) !!}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.